# Beginner CSS question. Can you make a link not a link with a class?

Tags: css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuGY6.png)I'm at the very beginning, making a navigation bar and altering the one I'm on. I just want to know if I can make the link of the page I'm currently on, not appear 
as a link with a class or do I have to just delete the href in the A?

```
   <nav>
        <a href="index.html" > Home </a> |   

        <a> About</a> |

       <!---- <a href="about.html" class="youarehere" > About</a> | -->

        <a href="Study.html"> Inspiration</a>  
    </nav>
```

Comment: "not appear as a link" - do you mean removing just the underline, or do you mean making it no longer work as a clickable link?

Comment: Can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: I made one. I want to make it without the underline and not cliclable.

Comment: ya basically not a link.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href=https://somesite.com" class="someclass">Link</a>
```

The A HREF is needed for the link to be a link as it's the Hypertext Reference. The class is optional but can be used for styling, ie:

```
.someclass {color: red; font-size: 20px;}
```

Comment: ty for answer but I mean I just want it not to be a link anymore and was wondering if i can add a class like youarehere. can of a weird question I'm' just curious if it can be done i know i can just do it like i have in my code.

Comment: Yeah you could just remove the a href and have it in a div or span, ie:
<span class="youarehere">youarehere</span> or <div class="youarehere">youarehere</div> then style like so
.youarehere {color: #fff;)